# What happens if you don't set ConnectionPolicy.ConnectionProtocol when using ConnectionMode.Direct?

Tags: c#, azure, tcp, azure-cosmosdb, nat

I was reading this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/nosql/performance-tips?tabs=trace-net-fx#networking) about Azure CosmosDB connection policies.

It says if you're using `ConnectionMode = ConnectionMode.Direct`, then you also need to set the `ConnectionProtocol`.

This [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/nosql/sdk-connection-modes#available-connectivity-modes) says `ConnectionMode.Direct` uses TCP, so I assume I should set `ConnectionProtocol` to `Protocol.Tcp`

Since the default value for the `Protocol` enum is `Https`, what would happen if you don't set it, would it default to `Https`?

If it does default to `Https`, would this cause any issues?

Here's my code:

```
var connectionPolicy = new ConnectionPolicy
{
    //ConnectionProtocol = Protocol.Tcp, // This is not set!
    ConnectionMode = ConnectionMode.Direct,
    RequestTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10),
    UserAgentSuffix = "ING",
    RetryOptions = new RetryOptions
    {
        MaxRetryAttemptsOnThrottledRequests = 5,
        MaxRetryWaitTimeInSeconds = 2
    }
};

var client = new DocumentClient(new Uri(endpoint), authKey, connectionPolicy, ConsistencyLevel.Session);
```

Here's the `Protocol` enum for reference:

```
public enum Protocol
{           
    Https,            
    Tcp
}
```

We've started getting `ServiceUnavailableException` and SNAT port exhaustion errors, so am wondering if this has anything to do with it.

Comment: Learn you 7 network layers and do not mix layers.  TCP is transport layer and http(s) is application layer.  HTTP(s) uses TCP as transport layer.  A HTTP message is broken into one or more TCP datagrams.  HTTP has three versions 1) HTTP 1.0 - stream mode 2) HTTP 1.1 chunk mode 3) HTTP 2.0 - Enhanced mode.  HTTPS is encrypted and uses TLS before the request is sent to establish encryption.  I assume if TCP is not used the UDP is used.  UDP is very similar to TCP except each message is not acknowledged.  HTTP and HTTPS will not communicate since one is encrypted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For V2 SDK the default would be `Https`. You would end up in `Direct/HTTPS` mode, not `Direct/TCP` nor `Gateway`.

`Direct/HTTPS` while valid and would work, is no longer part of any of the recommendations on the docs (https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/cosmos-db/sql/sql-sdk-connection-modes). If you need to use HTTPs, use `Gateway`, if you want to use `Direct`, use `Direct/TCP`.

The V3 SDK removed the possibility of selecting `Direct/HTTPS` and it's just `Direct` (TCP) or `Gateway` (HTTP).

Regarding SNAT, please follow https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/cosmos-db/sql/troubleshoot-service-unavailable

Direct mode will use a higher number of connections by design, make sure the machine can support that and that you are following the Singleton pattern to avoid creating more connections instead of reusing them.

Comment: I'm looking at what ports need to be open according to `https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/nosql/sdk-connection-modes#service-port-ranges` but it only mentions Direct/TCP mode not Direct/HTTPS mode. Do you know what ports need to be open for Direct/HTTPS mode?

Comment: Also why is Direct/HTTPS not part of the recommendations? What makes it inferior to Direct/TCP mode?

Comment: I'm watching your video https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/nosql/conceptual-resilient-sdk-applications. It looks like Direct is only able to work with TCP. How is it possible for it to work with HTTP, wouldn't it need a Gateway for that?

Comment: Direct/HTTP was an option available on V2 SDK, technically it still works (if you have an older SDK), but for newer SDKs it was removed. Videos and content are normally covering the current content (not old). The main issue with Direct/HTTPS was around detecting network errors and availability (TCP allows more control on each event of the connection and request/receive loop, and better error detection)

Comment: Are you able to help with this?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74474090/how-to-use-cosmosclient-createandinitializeasync-with-cosmosclientbuilder-buil/74474243