# How to use CosmosClient.CreateAndInitializeAsync() with CosmosClientBuilder.Build()

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

This YouTube [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=McZIQhZpvew) @27:20 talks about populating the cache with routing info to avoid latency during a cold start.
You can either try to get a document you know doesn't exist, or you can use `CosmosClient.CreateAndInitializeAsync()`.

I already have this code set up:

```
private async Task<Container> CreateContainerAsync(string endpoint, string authKey)
{
    var cosmosClientBuilder = new CosmosClientBuilder(
            accountEndpoint: endpoint,
            authKeyOrResourceToken: authKey)
        .WithConnectionModeDirect(portReuseMode: PortReuseMode.PrivatePortPool, idleTcpConnectionTimeout: TimeSpan.FromHours(1))
        .WithApplicationName(UserAgentSuffix)
        .WithConsistencyLevel(ConsistencyLevel.Session)
        .WithApplicationRegion(Regions.AustraliaEast)
        .WithRequestTimeout(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(DatabaseRequestTimeoutInSeconds))
        .WithThrottlingRetryOptions(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(DatabaseMaxRetryWaitTimeInSeconds), DatabaseMaxRetryAttemptsOnThrottledRequests);

    var client = cosmosClientBuilder.Build();
    
    var databaseResponse = await CreateDatabaseIfNotExistsAsync(client).ConfigureAwait(false);
    
    var containerResponse = await CreateContainerIfNotExistsAsync(databaseResponse.Database).ConfigureAwait(false);

    return containerResponse;
}
```

Is there any way to incorporate `CosmosClient.CreateAndInitializeAsync()` with it to populate the cache?

If not, is it ok to do this to populate the cache?

```
public class CosmosClientWrapper
{   
    public CosmosClientWrapper(IKeyVaultFacade keyVaultFacade)
    {           
        var container = CreateContainerAsync(endpoint, authenticationKey).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

        // Get a document that doesn't exist to populate the routing info:
        container.ReadItemAsync<object>(Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), PartitionKey.None).GetAwaiter().GetResult();     
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point of CreateAndInitialize or BuildAndInitialize is to pre-establish the connections required to perform Data Plane operations to the desired containers (reference https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/cosmos-db/nosql/sdk-connection-modes#routing).

If the containers do not exist, then it makes no sense to use CreateAndInitialize or BuildAndInitialize because there are no connections that can be pre-established/warmed up, because there are no target backend endpoints to connect to. That is why the container/database information is required, because the only benefit is warming up the connections to the backend machines that support that/those container/s.

Comment: After the database/container have been been created, is it then good practice to retrieve a document that doesn't exist? (see my last code snippet in the question).

Comment: The way you are doing it (with a blocking call) is not recommended (GetAwaiter/GetResults), please see: https://github.com/davidfowl/AspNetCoreDiagnosticScenarios/blob/master/AsyncGuidance.md#avoid-using-taskresult-and-taskwait. The 404 read will populate some of the caches but it won't open connections to all partitions, so yes, it will help but no, it is not equal to CreateAndInitialize

Comment: I couldn't find an easy way to await an async method from a ctor when DI is used. I know there are some ways to do it but it requires significant code changes which I don't have time to implement unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Please see [`CosmosClientBuilder.BuildAndInitializeAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.cosmos.fluent.cosmosclientbuilder.buildandinitializeasync?view=azure-dotnet#microsoft-azure-cosmos-fluent-cosmosclientbuilder-buildandinitializeasync(system-collections-generic-ireadonlylist((system-valuetuple((system-string-system-string))))-system-threading-cancellationtoken)) which creates the cosmos client and initialize the provided containers. I believe this is what you are looking for.

Comment: But that requires the database and container IDs which don't yet exist. I later on use the CosmosClient to create them if they don't exist.

Comment: I see. I don't think there are any methods in the SDK that would do that.